Lyx opening Error dxgi.dll
Hi: I am trying to install Lyx 2.4.1 for windows 7 (ultimate x64) and I get this error when i try to open the Lyx that i have installed (Tex and Texworks already installed) : Lyx.exe error the procedure entry point CreateDXGIFactory2 could not ne located located in the dynamic link library dxgi.dll.
Whats the solution for this?
Thanks,
V
